# Riemann Hypothesis follows from the statement $M\left(x\right)=o_x(x^{\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon})$

Tags: riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis, mobius-function

Recall that the Mertens function is defined via:
$$M(n):=\sum_{n\ge x\ge 1} \mu(x)$$

Where $\mu$ is the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function).

Littlewood proved that if $M\left(x\right)=o_x(x^{\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon})$
for every $\varepsilon>0$ then Riemann Hypothesis follows. RH states that
all the zeros of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta\left(s\right)$
in the critical strip: $0\leq Re\left(s\right)\leq1$,
reside on the line $Re\left(s\right)=\frac{1}{2}$.

I am following the proof from the book [Riemann's Zeta Function](https://books.google.co.il/books/about/Riemann_s_Zeta_Function.html?id=ruVmGFPwNhQC&redir_esc=y)
 by Harold M. Edwards, page 260, in the book he states that:

$$\frac{1}{\zeta\left(s\right)}=s\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{M\left(x\right)}{x^{s+1}}dx=s\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{M\left(x\right)}{x^{s+1}}dx$$

And then proceed to say that if $M\left(x\right)$ grows less rapidly than $x^{\alpha}$ for some
$\alpha>0$ than this integral for $\frac{1}{\zeta\left(s\right)}$
converges for all $s$ in the halfplane $\left\{ Re\left(a-s\right)<0\right\} =\left\{ Re\left(s\right)>a\right\} $
and therefore, by analytic continuation, the function $\frac{1}{\zeta\left(s\right)}$
is analytic in this halfplane. So substitute $\alpha$ with $\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon$ will achieve that no poles exists in the half-plane $\left\{ Re\left(s\right)>\frac{1}{2}\right\}$.

So my question is this proves for $\left\{ Re\left(s\right)>\frac{1}{2}\right\}$ but what about the other half-plane $\left\{ 0<Re\left(s\right)<\frac{1}{2}\right\}$ ?

Comment: I believe I have once heard in a youtube video that _if_ there is a nontrivial zero $\gamma$ with $\mathrm{Im}(\gamma)<\frac12$, this zero appears in a pair with a zero $\gamma'$ with $\mathrm{Im}(\gamma')>\frac12$

Comment: By the functional equation for $\zeta(s)$, if $\rho$ is a zero of $\zeta(s)$, then so is $1 - \rho$ (and by the Schwartz reflection principle, so is $\overline{\rho}$ and $1 - \overline{\rho}$). So this answers your question.